# Can't get ffmpeg to copy a specific subtitle track

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, subtitle

I'm trying to convert mkv files to mp4. I have mkv files with these tracks as listed by ffprobe:

- Stream #0:0 video
- Stream #0:1 ita audio
- Stream #0:2 jpn audio
- Stream #0:3 ita subtitle
- Stream #0:4 ita subtitle
- Stream #0:5 eng subtitle

I'm trying to copy over streams 0, 2, and 5.

I could get streams 0 and 2 to code by using this command (there are also dos commands involved):

```
FORFILES /m *.mkv /s /c "cmd /c c:\ffmpeg.exe -i @FILE -map 0:0 -c:v copy -map 0:2 -c:a:1 -acodec @FNAME.mp4"
```

But I get the error of `Unable to find a suitable output format for '0:5' 0:5: Invalid argument` as soon as I try to run this command:

```
FORFILES /m *.mkv /s /c "cmd /c c:\ffmpeg.exe -i @FILE -map 0:0 -c:v copy -map 0:2 -c:a:1 -map 0:5 -c:s:2 -acodec @FNAME.mp4"
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.